# a functional space for the study of exponential sum

Tags: functional-analysis, exponential-sum

I would like to study the exponential sum in an appropriate functional space.

In particular:

$f(x): \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $

$f(x) = \chi_K \sum_{i=1}^{M} R_i \exp{(s_i x)}$

where $R_i, s_i \in \mathbb{C}  \forall i$, $M$ is finite and $K$ is a compact interval on $\mathbb{R}$.

I would like to know which functional space is span by this set of functions.
Is it possible to add some restrictions, or generalizations, in order to have a `good` closure for the functional space (i.e. Banach, Hilbert, etc...)?
References are really appreciated.

Comment: Do you want the span, or the closure of the span to be good?

Comment: I modified the question, I mean the closure. Thanks

Comment: Ok. Now this raises the question: do you have a norm in mind? Sup norm?

Comment: I have no particular norm in mind at the moment, the sup norm would be a good.